# How to use Sleep() in two threads at the same time while they are both outputting something? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization, sleep

I want to output text on two separate lines in the console at the same time.
I made the `write()` function which does an animation, like a typewriter when outputting the string passed as a parameter, with the `time` delay, also a parameter.
I made another function which changes the cursor position, `changeColumnLine()`.

**The program is made for Windows and nothing else.**

The problem is that right now it outputs, without the animation, this:

```
  dog
cat
```

(it also waits the `length of the word * time` before outputting this, which does output at the same time)

And it should output, letter by letter, on two separate lines `dog` and `cat` at the same time.

This is the basic `write()` function:

```
void write(string word, int time, int line)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            //changeColumnLine(i, line);
            cout << word.at(i);
            Sleep(time);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

And this is the one I made in hopes of fixing it when using threads (using C++ 20):

```
void write(string word, int time, int line)
{
    osyncstream syncout{ std::cout };
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        changeColumnLine(i, line);
        //this_thread::sleep_for(200ms); 
        syncout << word.at(i);
        //Sleep(time);
    }
    syncout << "\n";
}
```

This is the `changeColumnLine()` that I wrote:

```
void changeColumnLine(int pos_line, int pos_column)
{
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int x_pos = pos_line;
    int y_pos = pos_column;
    COORD screen;
    HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    screen.X = x_pos;
    screen.Y = y_pos;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOutput, screen);
}
```

And this is the `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    thread t1(write, "cat", 200, 1);
    thread t2(write, "dog", 200, 5);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This problem has been giving me a headache the past 3 days and I just seem to not be able to find an answer.

Comment: Why are two threads needed here? If you really want the threads, you need at least a mutex that can be locked while one thread operates on the console.

Comment: well i want to have two things being outputted at the same time, i dont want one after the other. If there is a better and simpler way to do this, i am all ears

Comment: In a single thread, just output to each line and continue to sleep?

Comment: Multiple threads outputting to the console at the same time is undefined behavior.  It could cause a crash.  You could get interleaving characters or lines.  The C++ console concept is single threaded.  You'll need to define "at the same time" and use mutexes or semaphores to control the console resource.

Comment: So, what happens to the console when Thread A locks the console, then sleeps?  Can Thread B access the console?  Hmmm.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the code should only lock access to the console while actively updating the console, not while sleeping. Lock, move to desired line, write new text, unlock. Sleep. Repeat.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews at the same time means i want that animation i am describing to happen on two separate lines in the console at the same time, i want dog and cat to have that animation on two separate lines, animating at the same time

Comment: @user17732522 what do you mean by that

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to use only one thread for an animation. The thread (1) identifies when the next screen update is needed, (2) sleeps until that time, (3) does the update, and then goes back to (1). One thread should be able to handle the `write()` calls and the `changeColumnLine()` calls for both lines.

Comment: @MickeyMoise You write just a single loop in a single thread. In the loop body you sleep 200ms, then you adjust the cursor for the first line and advance the animation on the first line, then you adjust the cursor for the second line and advance the second animation. Then you let the loop continue with the next iteration's sleep.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but those uses of `word.at(i)` are just a waste of time. You **know** that `I` is a valid index; there's no need to check it. Just use `word[I]`.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks man, that did the trick